# Any way to pause script temporarily in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

In AppleScript, is there any way to temporarily pause the script running for a certain amount of time?

This would be the equivalent to writing time.sleep(2) in python, where python pauses for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

AppleScript includes a **delay** command.

```
delay 5
display dialog "Hello, 5 seconds later"
```